# Automated georeferencing based on topological point pattern matching in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, vectorization, arcscan

I have a lot of building plans (PDF/PNG format) which I would like to automatically georeference. I have the base map "OS Mastermap Mono", which is use for a lot of the building plans.

If I use ArcScan to vectorise the PDF/PNG, is there a way for ArcMap to automatically georeference this layer as it shares the same background map?

To provide an example:

I load in the basemap OS Mastermap Mono.

I wish to georeference the following map, which is existing development:

[image]

And then overlay the proposed development:

[image]

The purpose is to have a GIS that visualises plans in a easier way than our current system which is just PDF documents, and allows us to calculate area of existing/proposed building space.

I hope this is clear as to what I'd like to eventually achieve, perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: You could try this: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-a-raster-automatically.htm but as it says, probably better suited to aerial images.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. "OR" questions are often closed as "too broad", since they could generate completely different correct answers.  Please choose a software package to be used, and **edit** the title, question, and tags to reflect this package.  Please also specify the version of the software you are using.

Comment: It does sound like something I can try but I am pessimistic of the outcome mostly because of the image scaling and rotation. If it did work and In terms of accuracy, I'd imagine it would be fairly good considering it uses the same base map. I did manual georeferencing and it was within 200mm for most points, which is certainly adequate enough for our use.